# Why Eclipse-JDT can not get binding info from a java project?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-jdt

First, this is not `Eclipse plugin` project. I have three files in my `testing` folder.

```
//A
import dd.B;
public class A {
    public void run() {
        B b = new B();
    }
}
//B
package dd;
public class B {
    String name;
    int id;
    private C c = new C();
}
//C
package dd;
public class C {
    int x;
    int y;
}
```

Then I use `ASTParser` to get AST of A.java.

```
private static final String path = "F:/testing/A.java";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ASTParser parser = ASTParser.newParser(AST.JLS8);
        String content = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(path));
        parser.setSource(content.toCharArray());
        parser.setKind(ASTParser.K_COMPILATION_UNIT);
        parser.setUnitName("A");
        String[] sourcepathEntries = {"F:/testing"};
        String[] encodings = {"UTF-8"};
        String[] classPath = {"C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_151/lib"};
        parser.setEnvironment(classPath, sourcepathEntries, encodings, true);
        parser.setResolveBindings(true);
        parser.setBindingsRecovery(true);
        CompilationUnit cu = (CompilationUnit)parser.createAST(null);
        DemoVisitor dv = new DemoVisitor();
        cu.accept(dv);
    }
```

This is my `DemoVisitor`

```
public boolean visit(ClassInstanceCreation node) {
    ITypeBinding tb = node.resolveTypeBinding();
    System.out.println(tb);
    return super.visit(node);
}
```

My console output is

```
public class dd.B
    extends java.lang.Object
/*   fields   */
[unresolved] <no type> name
[unresolved] <no type> id
private [unresolved] <no type> c
/*   methods   */
public void <init>()
```

The fields in class B are `unresolved` although I set `parser` environment before. So is it possible to get complete binding map information of a java project.

Comment: You can't specify a directory containing .jar files as part of the classpath to the Java runtime or `javac`, so why are you doing it here?

Comment: Are B.java & C.java stored in a sub-directory "dd"? As I can't immediately find a problem in your code, I suggest you inspect `cu.getProblems()` for any compile errors.

Comment: Yes. B & C are stored in a sub-directory 'dd'. I set `sourcepathEntries` as my project folder and `parse` a single java file. I think I can get whole binding info of this AST only in this way. Is that right?@StephanHerrmann

Comment: The compilation is OK. I can get the `CompilationUnit` of class A. I hope I can get the object and object.method definition binding to ohter classes if they are in this `CompilationUnit`. But now I don't know how to set the sourcepathEntries. @StephanHerrmann

Comment: I read `ASTParser` source code this weekend. I find that there will be more details using Java Model instead of using standard java files so I have a question that is it possible to convert a folder including java files to a Eclipse java project. In this way I can get whole mapping information when no  `IJavaProject`.@StephanHerrmann